# Problems with getting an assoccation to display all of its belonging models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm creating a registration system for my University.

I've got two models, one being `Register` and the other being `Student`.
A `Register` has many `Students`, and I have depicted the following in their respective `.rb` files:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :register
attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :university_id

class Register < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :module_class
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :students
  attr_accessible :date, :present, :time_of_arrival, :student_id, :module_class_id, :event_id
```

The tables look like this, from the `schema.rb` file:

```
  create_table "registers", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "student_id"
    t.boolean  "present"
    t.integer  "module_class_id"
    t.integer  "event_id"
    t.time     "time_of_arrival"
    t.date     "date"
    t.datetime "created_at",      :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      :null => false
  end

  add_index "registers", ["event_id"], :name => "index_registers_on_event_id"
  add_index "registers", ["module_class_id"], :name => "index_registers_on_module_class_id"
  add_index "registers", ["student_id"], :name => "index_registers_on_student_id"
```

My question now is that, I want to be able to view a list of students within a Register, in order to mark them Present or Absent (in `register/1` for instance). This is how it looks like currently:
[image]

However, at the moment I can only assign one student to a register, and the `Present` checkbox appears (This is in the `register/new` page) [image: Printscreen of New Register page].

The `register` index itself looks like this:
[image]

I'm using `simple_form` gem for the forms, in case that gives more clues.

EDIT: Added the Diagram from RubyMine to show dependancies:
[image]

Comment: `ModuleClass` is a particularly unfortunate class name in ruby...

Comment: Images don't help us debug your code. Show the code the outputs the students. Show the code that saves the students (to prove you're making the associations correctly).

Comment: What exactly do you need @Deefour? And yes @PinnyM, very unfortunate, as `Module` and `Class` are already defined by Ruby, hence I had to come up with this

Answer (score 0):

A Register has many students you say, then why do you use `belongs_to :student` and added a `student_id` column in your register-table?

Comment: Ok i changed that, must have forgotten to taken it out.
I'm still unable however to select a whole list of students to be part of one register

Comment: This is the `register/_form.html.erb` file
`<%= simple_form_for(@register) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.association :students %>
    <%= f.input :present, :autofocus => true %>
    <%= f.association :module_class %>
    <%= f.association :event %>
   <%= f.input :time_of_arrival %>
    <%= f.input :date %>
 </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>`

And the view part for the student in the `show` is:
`<p>
  <b>Student:</b>
  <%= Student.find_by_id(@register.student_id).name %>
</p>`